# Unable to use custom variables in Gradle extension

Tags: java, gradle, jib

I'm using JIB (not super relevant) and I want to pass in variables from command line in my deployment script.

I append using `-PinputTag=${DOCKER_TAG} -PbuildEnv=nonprod` in my gradle command, which is cool. But when it's missing, I want that ternary to kick in.

I'm getting the error:

```
Could not get unknown property 'inputTag' for project ':webserver' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

```
def inputTag = inputTag ?: 'latest'
def buildEnv = buildEnv ?: 'nonprod'
jib {
    container {
        mainClass = 'com.example.hi'
    }
    to {
        image = 'image/cool-image'
        tags = ['latest', inputTag]
    }
    container {
        creationTime = 'USE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
        ports = ['8080']
        jvmFlags = ['-Dspring.profiles.active=' + buildEnv]
    }
}
```

### Found Solution

```
def inputTag = project.hasProperty('inputTag') ? project.property('inputTag') : 'latest'
def buildEnv = project.hasProperty('buildEnv') ? project.property('buildEnv') : 'nonprod'
```

This seems to be working, is this the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
image = 'image/cool-image:' + (project.findProperty('inputTag') ?: 'latest')
```

Note `jib.to.tags` are *additional* tags. `jib.to.image = 'image/cool-image'` already implies `image/cool-image:latest`, so no need to duplicate `latest` in `jib.to.tags`.